# Finding all the entries in a table having the column containing a substring

Tags: android, sql, database, android-room

I am using Room database in android(SQL) and I have a table that contains date as a column stored as a string of format 2000-01-31. I want to get all the entries in the table according to their respective month. I was thinking of using

```
SELECT * FROM `Transactions` WHERE Date LIKE '%01%
```

But in this way, I will have to write separate queries for each month.
I want to get the entries month-wise and show them in my android application.

My table looks like this...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answers the question that was originally asked.

Do not use string operations on dates.  If you want a particular month of a particular year, then use:

```
where date >= '2021-01-01' and date < '2021-02-01'
```

If you want all Januaries, then something like this:

```
where month(date) = 1
```

`month()` is a common function for this purpose, but it might vary depending on your database.

Comment: But with this method also i will have to make a separate query for each month Also i have edited my question and added my table to give an idea of how it looks

Comment: @KarmveerSingh . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question, you should ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all the entries in the table according to their respective month

So, you want to get all the entries (all the months), but sorted in some order, you can use `ORDER BY` either `ASC` or `DESC`

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the month as a parameter instead of hardcoding it, similar to

```
@Query("select * from Transactions where Date like '%-' || :month || '-%'")
public abstract List<Payment> getDataForMonth(String month);
```

for example, if the month is 03, the generated query will look like this.

`select * from Transactions where Date like '%-03-%'`

Also, storing date as Long(in milliseconds) instead of String will allow greater flexibility for querying.